# Deduct 10% transaction fee when user donates userpoints to another user using rules - Drupal 7

Tags: 7, rules, userpoints

I want to use rules to deduct 10% of the transaction amount from a donor each time he donates userpoints to another user using the userpoints_donate contrib module. Currently there are no rules events or actions from the userpoints_donate contrib module

possible events: user donates points to another user

possible conditions: donation_amount <=> a particular value

possible actions: grant points to donor = (donation_amount * -0.1, i.e grant -10% of donation_amount to donor)

How can i achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you see userpoints_donate.module `userpoints_donation_giveform_submit` function is reponsible to award points to another user

```
/**
 * Submit function to give another user points.
 */
function userpoints_donation_giveform_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  global $user;

  $points = $form_state['values']['amount'];
  $to = $form_state['validated_account'];

  $tid = NULL;
  if (isset($form_state['values']['tid'])) {
    $tid = $form_state['values']['tid'];
  }

  $params = array(
    'uid'    => $to->uid,
    'points' => $points,
    'operation'  => 'userpoints_donation_received',
    'entity_type' => 'user',
    'entity_id' => $user->uid,
    'description' => $form_state['values']['reason'],
    'tid'    => $tid,
  );
  userpoints_userpointsapi($params);

  $params = array(
    'uid'    => $user->uid,
    'points' => -$points,
    'operation'  => 'userpoints_donation_given',
    'entity_type' => 'user',
    'entity_id' => $to->uid,
    'description' => $form_state['values']['reason'],
    'tid'    => $tid,
  );
  userpoints_userpointsapi($params);
}
```

As you see above

userpoints_userpointsapi($params); is called to award $points with transaction operation userpoints_donation_received .

You can use hook_userpoints($op, $params = array()) to act upon certain operations. When other modules award  points to a user, your hook will be called, among others.

> $op: The operation to be acted upon.
>       'setting'
>         Pass a field set and fields that would be displayed in the userpoints
>         settings page. For example, this can be used for your program to ask
>         the admin to set a number of points for certain actions your module
>         performs. The function should return an array object conforming to
>         FormsAPI structure.
>
> 'points before'   Calls your module, and others, before the points are
>   processed. You can   prevent points from being awarded by returning
>   FALSE.
>
> 'points after'   Calls your module, and others, after points are
>   processed. You can take   certain actions if you so wish. Return value
>   is ignored.
>
> The $params variable is the original $params array as sent to
>   userpoints_userpointsapi

- Using "Points after" $op and  in $params check for operation "userpoints_donation_received"  you make a call to deduct 10 % points using..

userpoints_userpointsapi($params); API function..

```
<?php
function YOURMODULENAME_userpoints($op, $params) {
  if ($op == "points after") {
    if ($params['operation'] == "userpoints_donation_received") {
      $transaction_params = $params;
      $transaction_params['points'] = -( $transaction_params['points'] / 10);
      $transaction_params['operation'] = "userpoints_donation_transaction_fee";
      $transaction_params['description'] = "Transaction Fee";
      userpoints_userpointsapi($transaction_params);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation and code. I'll try this out now and accept your answer if it works, i appreciate.

Comment: when i try this code in a custom module, i get the code printed out on my screen: function userpoints_commission_userpoints($op, $params) { if ($op == "points after") { if ($params['operation'] == "userpoints_donation_received") { $transaction_params = $params; $transaction_params['points'] = -( $transaction_params['points'] / 10); $transaction_params['operation'] = "userpoints_donation_transaction_fee"; $transaction_params['description'] = "Transaction Fee"; userpoints_userpointsapi($transaction_params); } } }

Comment: the code also shows up as ajax error on screen when i try to perform any userpoints transaction. apart from that, it just shows up at the top of every page

Comment: Wrap them up with <?php tags..

Comment: Oh, my bad! Thanks alot, the code works now, but it deducts 10% credit from both donor and receiver. how can i make the deduction to be for only donor but not receiver? (Just lke the original question reads). Thanks.

Comment: It should be called only once since we are checking for $params['operation']... Try to put drupal_set_message("<pre>" . print_r($params, 1) . "</pre>"); inside second if condition observe what happens...

Comment: This my observation: The 500 points are deducted from donor but not credited to receiver, the 10% was deducted from receiver but not from donor: Array
(
    [uid] => 211  //receiver user
    [points] => 500
    [operation] => userpoints_donation_received
    [entity_type] => user
    [entity_id] => 1  //donor user
    [description] => some donation
    [tid] => 
    [reference] => 
    [display] => 
    [status] => 0
    [expired] => 
    [parent_txn_id] => 
    [expirydate] => 0
    [time_stamp] => 1396955841
    [changed] => 1396955841
    [txn_id] => 6
    [approver_uid] => 0
)

Comment: disabling the custom module, the credit and deduction works fine with the userpoints donation module, just troubleshooting to see the problem isn't from donation module